# Magento2: How we can add cacheable block on cart page using block_html cache type?

Tags: magento2, cache, shopping-cart, block-html

I want to add a cacheable block on the cart page. The cacheable block should be cached using the block_html cache type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I achieved this without creating a custom block. Here is the layout code:**

**Layout file:** checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="custom.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-container" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cacheable_block" template="[Namespace]_[ModuleName]::cachedblock.phtml" cacheable="true">
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- Set your desired cache lifetime in seconds -->
                        <argument name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="number">3600</argument>
                        <argument name="cache_tags" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="cache_tag_name" xsi:type="string">block_html</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a cacheable block on the cart page in Magento 2 using the block_html cache type,

you need to define a custom block in your module that extends **\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template**,

override the _construct method to include cache_lifetime
and cache_tags with **\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Block::CACHE_TAG**,

and implement **getCacheKeyInfo** for unique cache key generation. Then,
add your block to the **checkout_cart_index.xml**  layout with the **cacheable="true"** attribute and specify the template file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code I have added a sample cart Summary section.

```
// app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Block/CartSummary.php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CartSummary extends Template
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addData([
            'cache_lifetime' => 3600, // Cache lifetime in seconds
            'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart::CACHE_TAG],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Create or modify the layout XML file associated with the cart page to use your custom block class.

```
<!-- app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\CartSummary" name="checkout.cart.summary" template="YourVendor_YourModule::cart/summary.phtml" cacheable="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And then run below command.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Let me know if any queries.

**`Thanks.`**